# R: no applicable method for 'gaussiansmooth' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')" or "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster')

Tags: r, raster, gaussian, gaussianblur

I am trying to use the function `gaussiansmooth` but I am receiving an error: `Error in UseMethod("gaussiansmooth") : no applicable method for 'gaussiansmooth' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')".`

From the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/github/ethanplunkett/gridkernel/man/gaussiansmooth.html) it states that the input should be a grid object in memory. This is one of my many tests:

```
library(raster)
library(gridkernel)
library(gridprocess)

pan = raster("path/pan15.tif")

smoothed = gaussiansmooth(m,
                          sd = 0.5 * 920) # the multiplication is because I want my pixel size to become 460m.
```

In the documentation's example they used a `matrix`, but the same error occurs: `Error in UseMethod("gaussiansmooth") : no applicable method for 'gaussiansmooth' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')".`
Here is the same code but with a `matrix` instead of a satellite image.

```
pan = raster("path/pan15.tif")

m = as.matrix(pan)

smoothed = gaussiansmooth(m,
                          sd = 0.5 * 920)
```

The goal here is to change the pixel size of my image from 15m to 460m by applying a `Gaussian filter`. This is different from a 'simple' resampling method (e.g., nearest neighbor) because I am trying to model a point spread function.

From [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18_1Kshb8WbT04gwOw4d_xhfQenULDXdB?usp=sharing) you can download my image.

Comment: I see. Okay, but at least could someone help to figure it out? I posted a question there as well and the person who developed the package replied but I can't reproduce his steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the package replied to my question on `Github` and it turned out it was very simple. I just had to convert my `raster` into a `grid` object.

```
library(raster)
library(gridkernel)
library(gridprocess)

pan = raster("path/pan15.tif")
g = as.grid(pan)
```